# How to use temporary variables in select query in Postgresql equivalent to Mysql?

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating DB from Mysql to Postgresql, so that Iam struggling to use temporary variables in the select query as it giving error near ':=' Please go through the below queries for reference...

**Mysql query:**

```
SELECT
    @totalHours \:= FLOOR(
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, StartDate, EndDate)
    ) AS totalHours
FROM
    tableName @expectedEnd = CASE
WHEN @totalHours = 0 THEN
    (
        act.EndDate + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    )
ELSE
    EndDate
END AS expectedEnd @totalHours = CASE
WHEN @totalHours = 0 THEN
    (@totalHours + 24)
ELSE
    @totalHours
END AS exptotalHours;
```

**Postgresql query:**

```
SELECT
    @totalHours := abs(
        extract(
            epoch
            FROM
                (StartDate - EndDate)
        ) / 3600
    ) AS totalHours
FROM
    tableName @expectedEnd = CASE
WHEN @totalHours = 0 THEN
    (EndDate + INTERVAL '1 DAY')
ELSE
    EndDate
END AS expectedEnd @totalHours = CASE
WHEN @totalHours = 0 THEN
    (@totalHours + 24)
ELSE
    @totalHours
END AS exptotalHours;
```

Note: Declaring a variable first and reusing the same in other select query is not possible in my case

I have tried in different ways to store the value in temporary vaiables, but I couldn't... Anybody please give me a solution for this

*I appreciate your kind help*

Comment: Please explain what that query is doing. Ideally by supplying some sample data and the expected output based on that data. I have no idea what `FROM tableName @expectedEnd = CASE ... end` is doing. How can you use a variable as a table alias and compare that table alias it to a scalar expression

Comment: I guess the closet for session user defined variables would be `set_config('udv.total_hours','3',false)` and `current_setting('udv.total_hours')::int`, but won't take responsibility for porting the query above

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do with your query. but maybe postgres WITH : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html